# time() with clearTime - just today at 12:00 AM

Tags: php, date, datetime

What would be a fastest (mosteffective) way to that value in PHP ? time() gives me full timestamp with date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/strtotime), you could do :

```
$today = strtotime('00:00:00');

var_dump($today);
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $today));
```

And you'd get the following output :

```
int 1301436000
string '2011-03-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

Or, using the [**`DateTime`**][2] class :

```
$dt = new DateTime('00:00:00');

var_dump($dt->format('U'));
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

which would get that output :

```
string '1301436000' (length=10)
string '2011-03-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest code-version would be

```
$midnight = strtotime("today midnight");
```

as for efficiency, you'll have to benchmark it. strtotime is a huge beast under the hood, and while this code is compact, it could well be thousands of lines of code internally to accomplish what a few lines of code with the DateTime object would do.

Answer (score 1):

Before you use `strtotime()` be sure that your server's PHP config has correct timezone set.

Test it

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

That may be problem if you use localhost (sometimes) or server in other country. Timestamp does not observe timezone setting but function **strtotime()** certainly does!

if needed, set timezone from code before using `strtotime()`, `date()` or something like that

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Injoy

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to modify it into a string? check out date()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php